# Trouble finding correct peaks when using pracma::findpeaks in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, signal-processing

I am having trouble getting the correct peaks using `findpeaks`

```
dat <- structure(list(Temp = c(36.36, 36.37, 36.38, 36.37, 36.37, 36.35, 
36.34, 36.33, 36.34, 36.33, 36.32, 36.31, 36.3, 36.29, 36.28, 
36.27, 36.27, 36.28, 36.27, 36.25, 36.24, 36.22, 36.22, 36.2, 
36.19, 36.2, 36.2, 36.22, 36.22, 36.21, 36.21, 36.21, 36.21, 
36.21, 36.21, 36.22, 36.22, 36.23, 36.24, 36.24, 36.24, 36.24, 
36.25, 36.25, 36.24, 36.24, 36.23, 36.23, 36.22, 36.22, 36.21, 
36.2, 36.19, 36.19, 36.19, 36.2, 36.2, 36.21, 36.22, 36.23, 36.23, 
36.23, 36.23, 36.23, 36.24, 36.25, 36.24, 36.24, 36.24, 36.24, 
36.25, 36.25, 36.27, 36.27, 36.28, 36.28, 36.27, 36.26, 36.26, 
36.26, 36.25, 36.25, 36.25, 36.24, 36.24, 36.24, 36.24, 36.23, 
36.22, 36.21, 36.21, 36.2, 36.2, 36.19, 36.19, 36.18, 36.18, 
36.18, 36.18, 36.18, 36.17, 36.17, 36.17, 36.17, 36.17, 36.18, 
36.18, 36.19, 36.18, 36.19, 36.19, 36.19, 36.19, 36.19, 36.18, 
36.18, 36.16, 36.16, 36.15, 36.15, 36.15, 36.14, 36.12, 36.11, 
36.11, 36.11, 36.11, 36.11, 36.1, 36.1, 36.1, 36.1, 36.11, 36.11, 
36.11, 36.11, 36.1, 36.1, 36.09, 36.09, 36.09, 36.09, 36.09, 
36.09, 36.1, 36.11, 36.12, 36.12, 36.12, 36.12, 36.12, 36.12, 
36.13, 36.13, 36.13, 36.14, 36.14, 36.14, 36.13, 36.13, 36.13, 
36.11, 36.1, 36.09, 36.09, 36.1, 36.11, 36.15, 36.17, 36.24, 
36.29, 36.43, 36.51, 36.7, 36.8, 37.01, 37.14, 37.41, 37.56, 
37.84, 38, 38.33, 38.5, 38.84, 39.01, 39.36, 39.55, 39.91, 40.1, 
40.48, 40.79, 40.98, 41.43, 41.62, 41.99, 42.18, 42.56, 42.74, 
43.13, 43.32, 43.7, 43.88, 44.15, 44.33, 44.69, 45.07, 45.25, 
45.75, 45.93, 46.3, 46.48, 46.84, 47.03, 47.43, 47.63, 48.01, 
48.19, 48.54, 48.7, 48.99, 49.12, 49.35, 49.54, 49.63, 49.77, 
49.82, 49.88, 49.89, 49.91, 49.91, 49.9, 49.9, 49.86, 49.83, 
49.77, 49.73, 49.65, 49.62, 49.53, 49.44, 49.39, 49.29, 49.24, 
49.14, 49.08, 48.96, 48.9, 48.78, 48.71, 48.59, 48.53, 48.41, 
48.35, 48.23, 48.18, 48.05, 47.98, 47.85, 47.79, 47.66, 47.59, 
47.47, 47.32, 47.26, 47.12, 47.05, 46.92, 46.85, 46.73, 46.68, 
46.56, 46.49, 46.37, 46.31, 46.18, 46.13, 46.02, 45.97, 45.88, 
45.83, 45.77, 45.75, 45.73, 45.74, 45.81, 45.85, 45.97, 46.03, 
46.17, 46.33, 46.43, 46.65, 46.76, 47.01, 47.13, 47.4, 47.54, 
47.81, 48.14, 48.29, 48.58, 48.73, 49.04, 49.2, 49.53, 49.7, 
50.03, 50.36, 50.52, 50.86, 51.03, 51.39, 51.65, 51.9, 52.06, 
52.5, 52.87, 53.05, 53.41, 53.59, 53.82, 54, 54.37, 54.7, 55.06, 
55.42, 55.61, 55.97, 56.15, 56.49, 56.65, 56.94, 57.06, 57.29, 
57.47, 57.55, 57.68, 57.74, 57.81, 57.83, 57.83, 57.82, 57.78, 
57.75, 57.66, 57.54, 57.48, 57.35, 57.28, 57.12, 57.03, 56.85, 
56.76, 56.57, 56.47, 56.25, 56.15, 55.94, 55.72, 55.62, 55.35, 
55.24, 55.01, 54.9, 54.68, 54.56, 54.32, 54.2, 53.96, 53.84, 
53.59, 53.47, 53.23, 53.01, 52.9, 52.71, 52.69, 52.55, 52.49, 
52.39, 52.35, 52.3, 52.28, 52.28, 52.34, 52.39, 52.45, 52.44, 
52.56, 52.61, 52.72, 52.79, 52.93, 52.97, 53.11, 53.29, 53.37, 
53.54, 53.62, 53.79, 53.88, 54.06, 54.25, 54.33, 54.51, 54.6, 
54.79, 54.88, 55.06, 55.21, 55.38, 55.56, 55.65, 55.83, 55.92, 
56.1, 56.19, 56.37, 56.46, 56.64, 56.74, 56.91, 57.07, 57.14, 
57.27, 57.33, 57.42, 57.45, 57.48, 57.49, 57.48, 57.48, 57.42, 
57.31, 57.24, 57.08, 56.99, 56.84, 56.74, 56.54, 56.44, 56.22, 
56.05, 55.89, 55.77, 55.54, 55.31, 55.2, 54.99, 54.88, 54.66, 
54.55, 54.34, 54.23, 54.03, 53.84, 53.68, 53.49, 53.4, 53.22, 
53.14, 52.97, 52.88, 52.72, 52.63, 52.46, 52.38, 52.2, 52.02, 
51.93, 51.76, 51.68, 51.51, 51.43, 51.23, 51.15, 50.99, 50.94, 
50.79, 50.72, 50.55, 50.46, 50.29, 50.21, 50.06, 49.91, 49.84, 
49.68, 49.6, 49.44, 49.36, 49.2, 49.13, 48.98, 48.91, 48.77, 
48.7, 48.56, 48.49, 48.35, 48.28, 48.14, 48.07, 47.94, 47.83, 
47.7, 47.64, 47.56, 47.51, 47.39, 47.25, 47.2, 47.09, 47.04, 
46.98, 46.94, 46.86, 46.82, 46.76, 46.72, 46.63, 46.6, 46.54, 
46.51, 46.48, 46.44, 46.39, 46.37, 46.34, 46.33, 46.3, 46.3, 
46.29, 46.28, 46.25, 46.24, 46.22, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.2, 46.19, 
46.19, 46.19, 46.18, 46.16, 46.16, 46.14, 46.13, 46.11, 46.1, 
46.09, 46.08, 46.06, 46.06, 46.05, 46.04, 46.02, 46, 45.98, 45.95, 
45.94, 45.9, 45.88, 45.85, 45.84, 45.81, 45.78, 45.73, 45.71, 
45.67, 45.66, 45.62, 45.59, 45.55, 45.54, 45.53, 45.52, 45.48, 
45.44, 45.37, 45.34, 45.29, 45.26, 45.2, 45.15, 45.12, 45.06, 
45.03, 44.98, 44.96, 44.9, 44.87, 44.8, 44.77, 44.71, 44.68, 
44.61, 44.58, 44.53, 44.5, 44.44, 44.41, 44.37, 44.35, 44.3, 
44.28, 44.24, 44.22, 44.14, 44.11, 44.05, 44.02, 43.98, 43.96, 
43.89, 43.86, 43.8, 43.78, 43.76, 43.75, 43.7, 43.67, 43.63, 
43.6, 43.54, 43.5, 43.41, 43.36, 43.3, 43.26, 43.19, 43.16, 43.12, 
43.1, 43.08, 43.07, 43.04, 43.02, 42.97, 42.92, 42.88, 42.87, 
42.82, 42.81, 42.78, 42.77, 42.74, 42.74, 42.72, 42.69, 42.68, 
42.63, 42.6, 42.54, 42.51, 42.46, 42.43, 42.37, 42.35, 42.32, 
42.3, 42.25, 42.24, 42.2, 42.18, 42.14, 42.13, 42.07, 42.05, 
42, 41.97, 41.93, 41.9, 41.86, 41.83, 41.8, 41.79, 41.76, 41.75, 
41.73, 41.72, 41.69, 41.67, 41.61, 41.58, 41.53, 41.5, 41.46, 
41.43, 41.39, 41.37, 41.32, 41.3, 41.26, 41.24, 41.19, 41.17, 
41.1, 41.07, 41.01, 40.99, 40.94, 40.92, 40.87, 40.84, 40.78, 
40.76, 40.74, 40.73, 40.7, 40.68, 40.64, 40.62, 40.57, 40.56, 
40.53, 40.53, 40.51, 40.5, 40.48, 40.47, 40.45, 40.44, 40.42, 
40.41, 40.41, 40.41, 40.4, 40.4, 40.39, 40.38, 40.35, 40.34, 
40.32, 40.32, 40.32, 40.32, 40.31, 40.3, 40.28, 40.28, 40.27, 
40.27, 40.27, 40.26, 40.25, 40.25, 40.26, 40.26, 40.26, 40.26, 
40.23, 40.22, 40.23, 40.23, 40.23, 40.23, 40.23, 40.22, 40.21, 
40.22, 40.22, 40.22, 40.22, 40.21, 40.2, 40.2, 40.19, 40.18, 
40.17, 40.16, 40.16, 40.15, 40.15, 40.15, 40.13, 40.11, 40.09, 
40.08, 40.08, 40.08, 40.08, 40.08, 40.09, 40.08, 40.08, 40.06, 
40.05, 40.04, 40.04, 40.04, 40.04, 40.02, 40.02, 40.01, 40.01, 
40.01, 39.98, 39.97, 39.93, 39.92, 39.91, 39.91, 39.9, 39.89, 
39.88, 39.87, 39.85, 39.86, 39.87, 39.87, 39.86, 39.86, 39.85, 
39.85, 39.86, 39.87, 39.87, 39.87, 39.87, 39.87, 39.85, 39.85, 
39.84, 39.83, 39.82, 39.81, 39.79, 39.78, 39.75, 39.74, 39.72, 
39.71, 39.7, 39.68, 39.66, 39.65, 39.64, 39.63, 39.6, 39.59, 
39.57, 39.57, 39.55, 39.54, 39.5, 39.49, 39.48, 39.47, 39.47, 
39.47, 39.47, 39.47, 39.47, 39.47, 39.46, 39.46, 39.46, 39.45, 
39.44, 39.42, 39.4, 39.38, 39.37, 39.35, 39.34, 39.31, 39.28, 
39.26, 39.24, 39.22, 39.2, 39.18, 39.17, 39.16, 39.16, 39.17, 
39.17, 39.16, 39.15, 39.14, 39.14, 39.14, 39.14, 39.14, 39.14, 
39.14, 39.13, 39.12, 39.12, 39.11, 39.11, 39.1, 39.1, 39.09, 
39.09, 39.08, 39.07, 39.07, 39.07, 39.07, 39.07, 39.07, 39.06, 
39.05, 39.04, 39.04, 39.03, 39.02, 39, 39, 38.99, 38.99, 38.99, 
39, 38.99, 38.99, 38.98, 38.98, 38.98, 38.99, 39, 39.01, 39.02, 
39.01, 38.99, 38.98, 38.96, 38.96, 38.96, 38.95, 38.94, 38.93, 
38.9, 38.89, 38.87, 38.86, 38.84, 38.84, 38.85, 38.85, 38.83, 
38.83, 38.83, 38.83, 38.83, 38.83, 38.82, 38.81, 38.81, 38.8, 
38.78, 38.78, 38.77, 38.77, 38.76, 38.74, 38.73, 38.73, 38.73, 
38.72, 38.72, 38.72, 38.72, 38.7, 38.69, 38.68, 38.68, 38.67, 
38.67, 38.65, 38.65, 38.62, 38.61, 38.6, 38.6, 38.59, 38.59, 
38.59, 38.59, 38.6, 38.59, 38.58, 38.59, 38.59, 38.59, 38.59, 
38.59, 38.58, 38.56, 38.55, 38.55, 38.54, 38.53, 38.51, 38.5, 
38.49, 38.47, 38.46, 38.44, 38.43, 38.4, 38.39, 38.38, 38.37, 
38.35, 38.34, 38.33, 38.32, 38.32, 38.31, 38.29, 38.27, 38.24, 
38.23, 38.21, 38.2, 38.17, 38.16, 38.15, 38.14, 38.12, 38.11, 
38.09, 38.09, 38.08, 38.08, 38.07, 38.06, 38.04, 38.03, 38.02, 
38.01, 38, 37.99, 37.98, 37.97, 37.95, 37.94, 37.93, 37.93, 37.92, 
37.92, 37.91, 37.91, 37.9, 37.9, 37.9, 37.9, 37.9, 37.9, 37.9, 
37.9, 37.89, 37.89, 37.88, 37.88, 37.88, 37.87, 37.86, 37.85, 
37.85, 37.86, 37.87, 37.87, 37.87, 37.88, 37.89, 37.89, 37.89, 
37.88, 37.88, 37.88, 37.87, 37.87, 37.87, 37.85, 37.85, 37.84, 
37.84, 37.83, 37.83, 37.82, 37.81, 37.81, 37.81, 37.8, 37.8, 
37.8, 37.8, 37.8, 37.79, 37.79, 37.78, 37.76, 37.76, 37.75, 37.75, 
37.75, 37.75, 37.74, 37.74, 37.74, 37.74, 37.74, 37.74, 37.74, 
37.74, 37.74, 37.74, 37.74, 37.74, 37.74, 37.74, 37.73, 37.73, 
37.73, 37.73, 37.74, 37.74, 37.74, 37.74, 37.74, 37.73, 37.73, 
37.73, 37.73, 37.73, 37.73, 37.71, 37.7, 37.7, 37.7, 37.7, 37.7, 
37.71, 37.7, 37.71, 37.7, 37.7, 37.7, 37.7, 37.71, 37.72, 37.72, 
37.74, 37.73, 37.72, 37.72, 37.71, 37.7, 37.69, 37.68, 37.68, 
37.68, 37.69, 37.69, 37.7, 37.7, 37.7, 37.69, 37.68, 37.67, 37.66, 
37.65, 37.65, 37.64, 37.64, 37.62, 37.62, 37.61, 37.6, 37.6, 
37.6, 37.58, 37.57, 37.56, 37.55, 37.54, 37.54, 37.55, 37.55, 
37.55, 37.54, 37.54, 37.54, 37.53, 37.53, 37.52, 37.52, 37.52, 
37.51, 37.51, 37.5, 37.49, 37.48, 37.49, 37.49, 37.5, 37.5, 37.51, 
37.52, 37.54, 37.54, 37.54, 37.54, 37.53, 37.52, 37.51, 37.5, 
37.51, 37.52, 37.51, 37.51, 37.51, 37.52, 37.53, 37.53, 37.53, 
37.52, 37.52, 37.52, 37.52, 37.51, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 
37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.49, 37.49, 
37.49, 37.49, 37.49, 37.48, 37.49, 37.49, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 
37.49, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.5, 37.49, 37.49, 37.49, 37.49, 37.49, 
37.49, 37.46, 37.45, 37.42, 37.42, 37.39, 37.37, 37.35, 37.34, 
37.33, 37.32, 37.31, 37.3, 37.29, 37.29, 37.28, 37.28, 37.27, 
37.26, 37.26, 37.26, 37.26, 37.26, 37.26, 37.25, 37.25, 37.24, 
37.24, 37.24, 37.24, 37.24, 37.24, 37.23, 37.23, 37.22, 37.21, 
37.21, 37.2, 37.19, 37.19, 37.18, 37.17, 37.15, 37.14, 37.12, 
37.11, 37.1, 37.1, 37.09, 37.08, 37.08, 37.09, 37.1, 37.11, 37.12, 
37.13, 37.14, 37.15, 37.16, 37.16, 37.17, 37.18, 37.18, 37.19, 
37.2, 37.21, 37.22, 37.22, 37.22, 37.22, 37.21, 37.21, 37.2, 
37.2, 37.18, 37.18, 37.16, 37.15, 37.14, 37.13, 37.12, 37.12, 
37.12, 37.12, 37.13, 37.13, 37.12, 37.11, 37.1, 37.08, 37.08, 
37.07, 37.07, 37.07, 37.07, 37.08, 37.08, 37.06, 37.05, 37.04, 
37.04, 37.04, 37.04, 37.04, 37.04, 37.03, 37.03, 37.02, 37.02, 
37.02, 37.01, 37, 37, 36.98, 36.97, 36.95, 36.95, 36.93, 36.93, 
36.92, 36.92, 36.91, 36.9, 36.91, 36.91, 36.91, 36.91, 36.91, 
36.91, 36.91, 36.91, 36.91, 36.9, 36.89, 36.89, 36.88, 36.88, 
36.87, 36.88, 36.89, 36.9, 36.9, 36.9, 36.9, 36.89, 36.88, 36.87, 
36.87, 36.88, 36.89, 36.88, 36.88, 36.88, 36.88, 36.88, 36.88, 
36.88, 36.88, 36.88, 36.88, 36.89, 36.89, 36.9, 36.91, 36.92, 
36.93, 36.93, 36.94, 36.94, 36.95, 36.96, 36.96, 36.96, 36.97, 
36.97, 36.97, 36.97, 36.97, 36.97, 36.96, 36.96, 36.97, 36.98, 
37, 37, 36.99, 36.99, 36.99, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 36.99, 36.99, 
36.98, 36.98, 36.98, 36.98, 36.98, 36.98, 36.98, 36.97, 36.96, 
36.95, 36.95, 36.95, 36.95, 36.95, 36.95, 36.95, 36.95, 36.93, 
36.93, 36.94, 36.94, 36.94, 36.93, 36.91, 36.91, 36.92, 36.93, 
36.93, 36.92, 36.91, 36.91, 36.91, 36.91, 36.9, 36.9, 36.9, 36.89, 
36.88, 36.86, 36.85, 36.85, 36.84, 36.84, 36.83, 36.82, 36.81, 
36.8, 36.8, 36.81, 36.82, 36.83, 36.83, 36.83, 36.83, 36.83, 
36.83, 36.83, 36.83, 36.84, 36.84, 36.85, 36.85, 36.85, 36.85, 
36.85, 36.85, 36.83, 36.83, 36.81, 36.81, 36.8, 36.8, 36.81, 
36.81, 36.81, 36.8, 36.8, 36.79, 36.79, 36.8, 36.79, 36.78, 36.78, 
36.78, 36.79, 36.79, 36.79, 36.78, 36.78, 36.8, 36.81, 36.82, 
36.82, 36.84, 36.85, 36.85, 36.85, 36.85, 36.85, 36.84, 36.84, 
36.83, 36.84, 36.85, 36.84, 36.83, 36.82, 36.8, 36.8, 36.8, 36.8, 
36.8, 36.79, 36.78, 36.77, 36.78, 36.78, 36.79, 36.79, 36.79, 
36.79, 36.79, 36.78, 36.77, 36.77, 36.78, 36.77, 36.77, 36.76, 
36.76, 36.76, 36.76, 36.76, 36.75, 36.75, 36.75, 36.75, 36.75, 
36.75, 36.75, 36.74, 36.74, 36.74, 36.73, 36.71, 36.71, 36.71, 
36.71, 36.71, 36.71, 36.7, 36.7, 36.69, 36.67, 36.66, 36.66, 
36.66, 36.66, 36.66, 36.66, 36.66, 36.65, 36.65, 36.66, 36.66, 
36.67, 36.67, 36.66, 36.66, 36.66, 36.67, 36.66, 36.64, 36.62, 
36.62, 36.62, 36.62, 36.61, 36.61, 36.6, 36.61, 36.6, 36.61, 
36.6, 36.61, 36.61, 36.63, 36.64, 36.64, 36.65, 36.65, 36.65, 
36.64, 36.65, 36.66, 36.66, 36.66, 36.66, 36.64, 36.64, 36.63, 
36.63, 36.63, 36.63, 36.61, 36.61, 36.61, 36.63, 36.63, 36.64, 
36.64, 36.65, 36.65, 36.64, 36.64, 36.63, 36.63, 36.63, 36.62, 
36.61, 36.61, 36.6, 36.59, 36.6, 36.6, 36.61, 36.61, 36.62, 36.62, 
36.63, 36.64, 36.65, 36.65, 36.66, 36.65, 36.65, 36.64, 36.64, 
36.64, 36.64, 36.64, 36.65, 36.66, 36.66, 36.66, 36.65, 36.65, 
36.65, 36.66, 36.66, 36.67, 36.67, 36.68, 36.69, 36.7, 36.7, 
36.7, 36.69, 36.69, 36.69, 36.69, 36.69, 36.7, 36.71, 36.73, 
36.74, 36.74, 36.75, 36.75, 36.76, 36.76, 36.76, 36.78, 36.78, 
36.79, 36.79, 36.8, 36.81, 36.82, 36.82, 36.81, 36.8, 36.79, 
36.79, 36.79, 36.79, 36.79, 36.79, 36.8, 36.81, 36.81, 36.81, 
36.81, 36.81, 36.81, 36.81, 36.82, 36.82, 36.83, 36.83, 36.84, 
36.84, 36.83, 36.83, 36.83, 36.83, 36.84, 36.84, 36.83, 36.83, 
36.83, 36.84, 36.84, 36.83, 36.83, 36.83, 36.84, 36.85, 36.86, 
36.88, 36.88, 36.87, 36.87, 36.88, 36.88, 36.88, 36.88, 36.87, 
36.87, 36.87, 36.87, 36.88, 36.88, 36.88, 36.88, 36.87, 36.87, 
36.87, 36.84, 36.83, 36.82, 36.82, 36.81, 36.81, 36.81, 36.81, 
36.82, 36.81, 36.81, 36.8, 36.79, 36.79, 36.8, 36.8, 36.8, 36.8, 
36.81, 36.82, 36.84, 36.84, 36.84, 36.84, 36.84, 36.85, 36.85, 
36.85, 36.84, 36.82, 36.81, 36.8, 36.79, 36.79, 36.8, 36.78, 
36.78, 36.78, 36.79, 36.78, 36.78, 36.78, 36.78, 36.77, 36.77, 
36.78, 36.79, 36.81, 36.81, 36.81, 36.81, 36.81, 36.82, 36.82, 
36.82, 36.82, 36.82, 36.81, 36.8, 36.79, 36.79, 36.79, 36.79, 
36.79, 36.77, 36.76, 36.76, 36.75, 36.74, 36.74, 36.72, 36.72, 
36.71, 36.71, 36.72, 36.72, 36.71, 36.71, 36.71, 36.71, 36.71, 
36.72, 36.72, 36.72, 36.71, 36.71, 36.72, 36.71, 36.7, 36.69, 
36.68, 36.67, 36.66, 36.65, 36.64, 36.63, 36.63, 36.61, 36.6, 
36.58, 36.59, 36.58, 36.59, 36.6, 36.61, 36.61, 36.61, 36.61, 
36.61, 36.61, 36.61, 36.6, 36.6, 36.6, 36.6, 36.6, 36.59, 36.6, 
36.6, 36.6, 36.6, 36.6, 36.6, 36.58, 36.57, 36.56, 36.54, 36.54, 
36.54, 36.54, 36.53, 36.52, 36.51, 36.51, 36.51, 36.51, 36.48, 
36.47, 36.47, 36.47, 36.47, 36.47, 36.47, 36.47, 36.47, 36.47, 
36.46, 36.46, 36.47, 36.47, 36.46, 36.46, 36.46, 36.45, 36.43, 
36.43, 36.42, 36.42, 36.41, 36.4, 36.4, 36.39, 36.39, 36.37, 
36.37, 36.38, 36.38, 36.38, 36.37, 36.35, 36.34, 36.34, 36.34, 
36.34, 36.34, 36.35, 36.36, 36.36, 36.36, 36.37, 36.36, 36.36, 
36.35), Time = c(0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1, 0.12, 0.14, 0.16, 0.18, 
0.2, 0.22, 0.24, 0.26, 0.28, 0.3, 0.32, 0.34, 0.36, 0.38, 0.4, 
0.42, 0.44, 0.46, 0.48, 0.5, 0.52, 0.54, 0.56, 0.58, 0.6, 0.62, 
0.64, 0.66, 0.68, 0.7, 0.72, 0.74, 0.76, 0.78, 0.8, 0.82, 0.84, 
0.86, 0.88, 0.9, 0.92, 0.94, 0.96, 0.98, 1, 1.02, 1.04, 1.06, 
1.08, 1.1, 1.12, 1.14, 1.16, 1.18, 1.2, 1.22, 1.24, 1.26, 1.28, 
1.3, 1.32, 1.34, 1.36, 1.38, 1.4, 1.42, 1.44, 1.46, 1.48, 1.5, 
1.52, 1.54, 1.56, 1.58, 1.6, 1.62, 1.64, 1.66, 1.68, 1.7, 1.72, 
1.74, 1.76, 1.78, 1.8, 1.82, 1.84, 1.86, 1.88, 1.9, 1.92, 1.94, 
1.96, 1.98, 2, 2.02, 2.04, 2.06, 2.08, 2.1, 2.12, 2.14, 2.16, 
2.18, 2.2, 2.22, 2.24, 2.26, 2.28, 2.3, 2.32, 2.34, 2.36, 2.38, 
2.4, 2.42, 2.44, 2.46, 2.48, 2.5, 2.52, 2.54, 2.56, 2.58, 2.6, 
2.62, 2.64, 2.66, 2.68, 2.7, 2.72, 2.74, 2.76, 2.78, 2.8, 2.82, 
2.84, 2.86, 2.88, 2.9, 2.92, 2.94, 2.96, 2.98, 3, 3.02, 3.04, 
3.06, 3.08, 3.1, 3.12, 3.14, 3.16, 3.18, 3.2, 3.22, 3.24, 3.26, 
3.28, 3.3, 3.32, 3.34, 3.36, 3.38, 3.4, 3.42, 3.44, 3.46, 3.48, 
3.5, 3.52, 3.54, 3.56, 3.58, 3.6, 3.62, 3.64, 3.66, 3.68, 3.7, 
3.72, 3.74, 3.76, 3.78, 3.8, 3.82, 3.84, 3.86, 3.88, 3.9, 3.92, 
3.94, 3.96, 3.98, 4, 4.02, 4.04, 4.06, 4.08, 4.1, 4.12, 4.14, 
4.16, 4.18, 4.2, 4.22, 4.24, 4.26, 4.28, 4.3, 4.32, 4.34, 4.36, 
4.38, 4.4, 4.42, 4.44, 4.46, 4.48, 4.5, 4.52, 4.54, 4.56, 4.58, 
4.6, 4.62, 4.64, 4.66, 4.68, 4.7, 4.72, 4.74, 4.76, 4.78, 4.8, 
4.82, 4.84, 4.86, 4.88, 4.9, 4.92, 4.94, 4.96, 4.98, 5, 5.02, 
5.04, 5.06, 5.08, 5.1, 5.12, 5.14, 5.16, 5.18, 5.2, 5.22, 5.24, 
5.26, 5.28, 5.3, 5.32, 5.34, 5.36, 5.38, 5.4, 5.42, 5.44, 5.46, 
5.48, 5.5, 5.52, 5.54, 5.56, 5.58, 5.6, 5.62, 5.64, 5.66, 5.68, 
5.7, 5.72, 5.74, 5.76, 5.78, 5.8, 5.82, 5.84, 5.86, 5.88, 5.9, 
5.92, 5.94, 5.96, 5.98, 6, 6.02, 6.04, 6.06, 6.08, 6.1, 6.12, 
6.14, 6.16, 6.18, 6.2, 6.22, 6.24, 6.26, 6.28, 6.3, 6.32, 6.34, 
6.36, 6.38, 6.4, 6.42, 6.44, 6.46, 6.48, 6.5, 6.52, 6.54, 6.56, 
6.58, 6.6, 6.62, 6.64, 6.66, 6.68, 6.7, 6.72, 6.74, 6.76, 6.78, 
6.8, 6.82, 6.84, 6.86, 6.88, 6.9, 6.92, 6.94, 6.96, 6.98, 7, 
7.02, 7.04, 7.06, 7.08, 7.1, 7.12, 7.14, 7.16, 7.18, 7.2, 7.22, 
7.24, 7.26, 7.28, 7.3, 7.32, 7.34, 7.36, 7.38, 7.4, 7.42, 7.44, 
7.46, 7.48, 7.5, 7.52, 7.54, 7.56, 7.58, 7.6, 7.62, 7.64, 7.66, 
7.68, 7.7, 7.72, 7.74, 7.76, 7.78, 7.8, 7.82, 7.84, 7.86, 7.88, 
7.9, 7.92, 7.94, 7.96, 7.98, 8, 8.02, 8.04, 8.06, 8.08, 8.1, 
8.12, 8.14, 8.16, 8.18, 8.2, 8.22, 8.24, 8.26, 8.28, 8.3, 8.32, 
8.34, 8.36, 8.38, 8.4, 8.42, 8.44, 8.46, 8.48, 8.5, 8.52, 8.54, 
8.56, 8.58, 8.6, 8.62, 8.64, 8.66, 8.68, 8.7, 8.72, 8.74, 8.76, 
8.78, 8.8, 8.82, 8.84, 8.86, 8.88, 8.9, 8.92, 8.94, 8.96, 8.98, 
9, 9.02, 9.04, 9.06, 9.08, 9.1, 9.12, 9.14, 9.16, 9.18, 9.2, 
9.22, 9.24, 9.26, 9.28, 9.3, 9.32, 9.34, 9.36, 9.38, 9.4, 9.42, 
9.44, 9.46, 9.48, 9.5, 9.52, 9.54, 9.56, 9.58, 9.6, 9.62, 9.64, 
9.66, 9.68, 9.7, 9.72, 9.74, 9.76, 9.78, 9.8, 9.82, 9.84, 9.86, 
9.88, 9.9, 9.92, 9.94, 9.96, 9.98, 10, 10.02, 10.04, 10.06, 10.08, 
10.1, 10.12, 10.14, 10.16, 10.18, 10.2, 10.22, 10.24, 10.26, 
10.28, 10.3, 10.32, 10.34, 10.36, 10.38, 10.4, 10.42, 10.44, 
10.46, 10.48, 10.5, 10.52, 10.54, 10.56, 10.58, 10.6, 10.62, 
10.64, 10.66, 10.68, 10.7, 10.72, 10.74, 10.76, 10.78, 10.8, 
10.82, 10.84, 10.86, 10.88, 10.9, 10.92, 10.94, 10.96, 10.98, 
11, 11.02, 11.04, 11.06, 11.08, 11.1, 11.12, 11.14, 11.16, 11.18, 
11.2, 11.22, 11.24, 11.26, 11.28, 11.3, 11.32, 11.34, 11.36, 
11.38, 11.4, 11.42, 11.44, 11.46, 11.48, 11.5, 11.52, 11.54, 
11.56, 11.58, 11.6, 11.62, 11.64, 11.66, 11.68, 11.7, 11.72, 
11.74, 11.76, 11.78, 11.8, 11.82, 11.84, 11.86, 11.88, 11.9, 
11.92, 11.94, 11.96, 11.98, 12, 12.02, 12.04, 12.06, 12.08, 12.1, 
12.12, 12.14, 12.16, 12.18, 12.2, 12.22, 12.24, 12.26, 12.28, 
12.3, 12.32, 12.34, 12.36, 12.38, 12.4, 12.42, 12.44, 12.46, 
12.48, 12.5, 12.52, 12.54, 12.56, 12.58, 12.6, 12.62, 12.64, 
12.66, 12.68, 12.7, 12.72, 12.74, 12.76, 12.78, 12.8, 12.82, 
12.84, 12.86, 12.88, 12.9, 12.92, 12.94, 12.96, 12.98, 13, 13.02, 
13.04, 13.06, 13.08, 13.1, 13.12, 13.14, 13.16, 13.18, 13.2, 
13.22, 13.24, 13.26, 13.28, 13.3, 13.32, 13.34, 13.36, 13.38, 
13.4, 13.42, 13.44, 13.46, 13.48, 13.5, 13.52, 13.54, 13.56, 
13.58, 13.6, 13.62, 13.64, 13.66, 13.68, 13.7, 13.72, 13.74, 
13.76, 13.78, 13.8, 13.82, 13.84, 13.86, 13.88, 13.9, 13.92, 
13.94, 13.96, 13.98, 14, 14.02, 14.04, 14.06, 14.08, 14.1, 14.12, 
14.14, 14.16, 14.18, 14.2, 14.22, 14.24, 14.26, 14.28, 14.3, 
14.32, 14.34, 14.36, 14.38, 14.4, 14.42, 14.44, 14.46, 14.48, 
14.5, 14.52, 14.54, 14.56, 14.58, 14.6, 14.62, 14.64, 14.66, 
14.68, 14.7, 14.72, 14.74, 14.76, 14.78, 14.8, 14.82, 14.84, 
14.86, 14.88, 14.9, 14.92, 14.94, 14.96, 14.98, 15, 15.02, 15.04, 
15.06, 15.08, 15.1, 15.12, 15.14, 15.16, 15.18, 15.2, 15.22, 
15.24, 15.26, 15.28, 15.3, 15.32, 15.34, 15.36, 15.38, 15.4, 
15.42, 15.44, 15.46, 15.48, 15.5, 15.52, 15.54, 15.56, 15.58, 
15.6, 15.62, 15.64, 15.66, 15.68, 15.7, 15.72, 15.74, 15.76, 
15.78, 15.8, 15.82, 15.84, 15.86, 15.88, 15.9, 15.92, 15.94, 
15.96, 15.98, 16, 16.02, 16.04, 16.06, 16.08, 16.1, 16.12, 16.14, 
16.16, 16.18, 16.2, 16.22, 16.24, 16.26, 16.28, 16.3, 16.32, 
16.34, 16.36, 16.38, 16.4, 16.42, 16.44, 16.46, 16.48, 16.5, 
16.52, 16.54, 16.56, 16.58, 16.6, 16.62, 16.64, 16.66, 16.68, 
16.7, 16.72, 16.74, 16.76, 16.78, 16.8, 16.82, 16.84, 16.86, 
16.88, 16.9, 16.92, 16.94, 16.96, 16.98, 17, 17.02, 17.04, 17.06, 
17.08, 17.1, 17.12, 17.14, 17.16, 17.18, 17.2, 17.22, 17.24, 
17.26, 17.28, 17.3, 17.32, 17.34, 17.36, 17.38, 17.4, 17.42, 
17.44, 17.46, 17.48, 17.5, 17.52, 17.54, 17.56, 17.58, 17.6, 
17.62, 17.64, 17.66, 17.68, 17.7, 17.72, 17.74, 17.76, 17.78, 
17.8, 17.82, 17.84, 17.86, 17.88, 17.9, 17.92, 17.94, 17.96, 
17.98, 18, 18.02, 18.04, 18.06, 18.08, 18.1, 18.12, 18.14, 18.16, 
18.18, 18.2, 18.22, 18.24, 18.26, 18.28, 18.3, 18.32, 18.34, 
18.36, 18.38, 18.4, 18.42, 18.44, 18.46, 18.48, 18.5, 18.52, 
18.54, 18.56, 18.58, 18.6, 18.62, 18.64, 18.66, 18.68, 18.7, 
18.72, 18.74, 18.76, 18.78, 18.8, 18.82, 18.84, 18.86, 18.88, 
18.9, 18.92, 18.94, 18.96, 18.98, 19, 19.02, 19.04, 19.06, 19.08, 
19.1, 19.12, 19.14, 19.16, 19.18, 19.2, 19.22, 19.24, 19.26, 
19.28, 19.3, 19.32, 19.34, 19.36, 19.38, 19.4, 19.42, 19.44, 
19.46, 19.48, 19.5, 19.52, 19.54, 19.56, 19.58, 19.6, 19.62, 
19.64, 19.66, 19.68, 19.7, 19.72, 19.74, 19.76, 19.78, 19.8, 
19.82, 19.84, 19.86, 19.88, 19.9, 19.92, 19.94, 19.96, 19.98, 
20, 20.02, 20.04, 20.06, 20.08, 20.1, 20.12, 20.14, 20.16, 20.18, 
20.2, 20.22, 20.24, 20.26, 20.28, 20.3, 20.32, 20.34, 20.36, 
20.38, 20.4, 20.42, 20.44, 20.46, 20.48, 20.5, 20.52, 20.54, 
20.56, 20.58, 20.6, 20.62, 20.64, 20.66, 20.68, 20.7, 20.72, 
20.74, 20.76, 20.78, 20.8, 20.82, 20.84, 20.86, 20.88, 20.9, 
20.92, 20.94, 20.96, 20.98, 21, 21.02, 21.04, 21.06, 21.08, 21.1, 
21.12, 21.14, 21.16, 21.18, 21.2, 21.22, 21.24, 21.26, 21.28, 
21.3, 21.32, 21.34, 21.36, 21.38, 21.4, 21.42, 21.44, 21.46, 
21.48, 21.5, 21.52, 21.54, 21.56, 21.58, 21.6, 21.62, 21.64, 
21.66, 21.68, 21.7, 21.72, 21.74, 21.76, 21.78, 21.8, 21.82, 
21.84, 21.86, 21.88, 21.9, 21.92, 21.94, 21.96, 21.98, 22, 22.02, 
22.04, 22.06, 22.08, 22.1, 22.12, 22.14, 22.16, 22.18, 22.2, 
22.22, 22.24, 22.26, 22.28, 22.3, 22.32, 22.34, 22.36, 22.38, 
22.4, 22.42, 22.44, 22.46, 22.48, 22.5, 22.52, 22.54, 22.56, 
22.58, 22.6, 22.62, 22.64, 22.66, 22.68, 22.7, 22.72, 22.74, 
22.76, 22.78, 22.8, 22.82, 22.84, 22.86, 22.88, 22.9, 22.92, 
22.94, 22.96, 22.98, 23, 23.02, 23.04, 23.06, 23.08, 23.1, 23.12, 
23.14, 23.16, 23.18, 23.2, 23.22, 23.24, 23.26, 23.28, 23.3, 
23.32, 23.34, 23.36, 23.38, 23.4, 23.42, 23.44, 23.46, 23.48, 
23.5, 23.52, 23.54, 23.56, 23.58, 23.6, 23.62, 23.64, 23.66, 
23.68, 23.7, 23.72, 23.74, 23.76, 23.78, 23.8, 23.82, 23.84, 
23.86, 23.88, 23.9, 23.92, 23.94, 23.96, 23.98, 24, 24.02, 24.04, 
24.06, 24.08, 24.1, 24.12, 24.14, 24.16, 24.18, 24.2, 24.22, 
24.24, 24.26, 24.28, 24.3, 24.32, 24.34, 24.36, 24.38, 24.4, 
24.42, 24.44, 24.46, 24.48, 24.5, 24.52, 24.54, 24.56, 24.58, 
24.6, 24.62, 24.64, 24.66, 24.68, 24.7, 24.72, 24.74, 24.76, 
24.78, 24.8, 24.82, 24.84, 24.86, 24.88, 24.9, 24.92, 24.94, 
24.96, 24.98, 25, 25.02, 25.04, 25.06, 25.08, 25.1, 25.12, 25.14, 
25.16, 25.18, 25.2, 25.22, 25.24, 25.26, 25.28, 25.3, 25.32, 
25.34, 25.36, 25.38, 25.4, 25.42, 25.44, 25.46, 25.48, 25.5, 
25.52, 25.54, 25.56, 25.58, 25.6, 25.62, 25.64, 25.66, 25.68, 
25.7, 25.72, 25.74, 25.76, 25.78, 25.8, 25.82, 25.84, 25.86, 
25.88, 25.9, 25.92, 25.94, 25.96, 25.98, 26, 26.02, 26.04, 26.06, 
26.08, 26.1, 26.12, 26.14, 26.16, 26.18, 26.2, 26.22, 26.24, 
26.26, 26.28, 26.3, 26.32, 26.34, 26.36, 26.38, 26.4, 26.42, 
26.44, 26.46, 26.48, 26.5, 26.52, 26.54, 26.56, 26.58, 26.6, 
26.62, 26.64, 26.66, 26.68, 26.7, 26.72, 26.74, 26.76, 26.78, 
26.8, 26.82, 26.84, 26.86, 26.88, 26.9, 26.92, 26.94, 26.96, 
26.98, 27, 27.02, 27.04, 27.06, 27.08, 27.1, 27.12, 27.14, 27.16, 
27.18, 27.2, 27.22, 27.24, 27.26, 27.28, 27.3, 27.32, 27.34, 
27.36, 27.38, 27.4, 27.42, 27.44, 27.46, 27.48, 27.5, 27.52, 
27.54, 27.56, 27.58, 27.6, 27.62, 27.64, 27.66, 27.68, 27.7, 
27.72, 27.74, 27.76, 27.78, 27.8, 27.82, 27.84, 27.86, 27.88, 
27.9, 27.92, 27.94, 27.96, 27.98, 28, 28.02, 28.04, 28.06, 28.08, 
28.1, 28.12, 28.14, 28.16, 28.18, 28.2, 28.22, 28.24, 28.26, 
28.28, 28.3, 28.32, 28.34, 28.36, 28.38, 28.4, 28.42, 28.44, 
28.46, 28.48, 28.5, 28.52, 28.54, 28.56, 28.58, 28.6, 28.62, 
28.64, 28.66, 28.68, 28.7, 28.72, 28.74, 28.76, 28.78, 28.8, 
28.82, 28.84, 28.86, 28.88, 28.9, 28.92, 28.94, 28.96, 28.98, 
29, 29.02, 29.04, 29.06, 29.08, 29.1, 29.12, 29.14, 29.16, 29.18, 
29.2, 29.22, 29.24, 29.26, 29.28, 29.3, 29.32, 29.34, 29.36, 
29.38, 29.4, 29.42, 29.44, 29.46, 29.48, 29.5, 29.52, 29.54, 
29.56, 29.58, 29.6, 29.62, 29.64, 29.66, 29.68, 29.7, 29.72, 
29.74, 29.76, 29.78, 29.8, 29.82, 29.84, 29.86, 29.88, 29.9, 
29.92, 29.94, 29.96, 29.98, 30, 30.02, 30.04, 30.06, 30.08, 30.1, 
30.12, 30.14, 30.16, 30.18, 30.2, 30.22, 30.24, 30.26, 30.28, 
30.3, 30.32, 30.34, 30.36, 30.38, 30.4, 30.42, 30.44, 30.46, 
30.48, 30.5, 30.52, 30.54, 30.56, 30.58, 30.6, 30.62, 30.64, 
30.66, 30.68, 30.7, 30.72, 30.74, 30.76, 30.78, 30.8, 30.82, 
30.84, 30.86, 30.88, 30.9, 30.92, 30.94, 30.96, 30.98, 31, 31.02, 
31.04, 31.06, 31.08, 31.1, 31.12, 31.14, 31.16, 31.18, 31.2, 
31.22, 31.24, 31.26, 31.28, 31.3, 31.32, 31.34, 31.36, 31.38, 
31.4, 31.42, 31.44, 31.46, 31.48, 31.5, 31.52, 31.54, 31.56, 
31.58, 31.6, 31.62, 31.64, 31.66, 31.68, 31.7, 31.72, 31.74, 
31.76, 31.78, 31.8, 31.82, 31.84, 31.86, 31.88, 31.9, 31.92, 
31.94, 31.96, 31.98, 32, 32.02, 32.04, 32.06, 32.08, 32.1, 32.12, 
32.14, 32.16, 32.18, 32.2, 32.22, 32.24, 32.26, 32.28, 32.3, 
32.32, 32.34, 32.36, 32.38, 32.4, 32.42, 32.44, 32.46, 32.48, 
32.5, 32.52, 32.54, 32.56, 32.58, 32.6, 32.62, 32.64, 32.66, 
32.68, 32.7, 32.72, 32.74, 32.76, 32.78, 32.8, 32.82, 32.84, 
32.86, 32.88, 32.9, 32.92, 32.94, 32.96, 32.98, 33, 33.02, 33.04, 
33.06, 33.08, 33.1, 33.12, 33.14, 33.16, 33.18, 33.2, 33.22, 
33.24, 33.26, 33.28, 33.3, 33.32, 33.34, 33.36, 33.38, 33.4, 
33.42, 33.44, 33.46, 33.48, 33.5, 33.52, 33.54, 33.56, 33.58, 
33.6, 33.62, 33.64, 33.66, 33.68, 33.7, 33.72, 33.74, 33.76, 
33.78, 33.8, 33.82, 33.84, 33.86, 33.88, 33.9, 33.92, 33.94, 
33.96, 33.98, 34, 34.02, 34.04, 34.06, 34.08, 34.1, 34.12, 34.14, 
34.16, 34.18, 34.2, 34.22, 34.24, 34.26, 34.28, 34.3, 34.32, 
34.34, 34.36, 34.38, 34.4, 34.42, 34.44, 34.46, 34.48, 34.5, 
34.52, 34.54, 34.56, 34.58, 34.6, 34.62, 34.64, 34.66, 34.68, 
34.7, 34.72, 34.74, 34.76, 34.78, 34.8, 34.82, 34.84, 34.86, 
34.88, 34.9, 34.92, 34.94, 34.96, 34.98, 35, 35.02, 35.04, 35.06, 
35.08, 35.1, 35.12, 35.14, 35.16, 35.18, 35.2, 35.22, 35.24, 
35.26, 35.28, 35.3, 35.32, 35.34, 35.36, 35.38, 35.4, 35.42, 
35.44, 35.46, 35.48, 35.5, 35.52, 35.54, 35.56, 35.58, 35.6, 
35.62, 35.64, 35.66, 35.68, 35.7, 35.72, 35.74, 35.76, 35.78, 
35.8, 35.82, 35.84, 35.86, 35.88, 35.9, 35.92, 35.94, 35.96, 
35.98, 36, 36.02, 36.04, 36.06, 36.08, 36.1, 36.12, 36.14, 36.16, 
36.18, 36.2, 36.22, 36.24, 36.26, 36.28, 36.3, 36.32, 36.34, 
36.36, 36.38, 36.4, 36.42, 36.44, 36.46, 36.48, 36.5, 36.52, 
36.54, 36.56, 36.58, 36.6, 36.62, 36.64, 36.66, 36.68, 36.7, 
36.72, 36.74, 36.76, 36.78, 36.8, 36.82, 36.84, 36.86, 36.88, 
36.9, 36.92, 36.94, 36.96, 36.98, 37, 37.02, 37.04, 37.06, 37.08, 
37.1, 37.12, 37.14, 37.16, 37.18, 37.2, 37.22, 37.24, 37.26, 
37.28, 37.3, 37.32, 37.34, 37.36, 37.38, 37.4, 37.42, 37.44, 
37.46, 37.48, 37.5, 37.52, 37.54, 37.56, 37.58, 37.6, 37.62, 
37.64, 37.66, 37.68, 37.7, 37.72, 37.74, 37.76, 37.78, 37.8, 
37.82, 37.84, 37.86, 37.88, 37.9, 37.92, 37.94, 37.96, 37.98, 
38, 38.02, 38.04, 38.06, 38.08, 38.1, 38.12, 38.14, 38.16, 38.18, 
38.2, 38.22, 38.24, 38.26, 38.28, 38.3, 38.32, 38.34, 38.36, 
38.38, 38.4, 38.42, 38.44, 38.46, 38.48, 38.5, 38.52, 38.54, 
38.56, 38.58, 38.6, 38.62, 38.64, 38.66, 38.68, 38.7, 38.72, 
38.74, 38.76, 38.78, 38.8, 38.82, 38.84, 38.86, 38.88, 38.9, 
38.92, 38.94, 38.96, 38.98, 39, 39.02, 39.04, 39.06, 39.08, 39.1, 
39.12, 39.14, 39.16, 39.18, 39.2, 39.22, 39.24, 39.26, 39.28, 
39.3, 39.32, 39.34, 39.36, 39.38, 39.4, 39.42, 39.44, 39.46, 
39.48, 39.5, 39.52, 39.54)), row.names = 2:1977, class = "data.frame")
```

Initially, I was subsetting my data by visually looking at where the peaks are on the graph and then finding the maximum value within each subset.

```
#Find 1st peak value
dat_peak1 <- subset(dat, Time > 3.5 & Time < 5.6)
dat_peak1_max <- max(dat_peak1$Temp)
[1] 49.91

#Find 2nd peak value
dat_peak2 <- subset(dat, Time > 5.6 & Time < 7.6)
dat_peak2_max <- max(dat_peak2$Temp)
[1] 57.83

#Find 3rd peak value
dat_peak3 <- subset(dat, Time > 7.6 & Time < 9.6)
dat_peak3_max <- max(dat_peak3$Temp)
[1] 57.49
```

I plotted the determined peak values to determine if they are indeed the peak values.

```
graph_peak<-ggplot(dat, height = 50) + 
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = Time, y = Temp),size=1)+
  geom_hline(yintercept = dat_peak1_max, color = "red")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = dat_peak2_max, color = "red")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = dat_peak3_max, color = "red")+
  xlim(0,10) #changed x-axis limits to better see the peaks
graph_peak
```

[image: See graph_peak here]

Now, for 3 peaks this seems to do the job but sometimes I need to analyze datasets that have more than 3 peaks. That's why I started looking into functions that can determine the peaks of my data. I have tried `turnpoints` as well as `quantmod::findPeaks` but that didn't seem to work that well for me as I prefer to get the actual values as an output instead of indices. And also, I'm getting multiple indices instead of just three. With that, I am posting this question solely to figure out how to make `pracma::findpeaks` work for my application. The biggest struggle for me is the weak documentation that does not help me tweak my code in order to get the peak values that I need to get. Below you will see my various attempts in getting the said peak values.

Attempt 2 - specify # of desired peaks which in this case is 3:

```
peak_val2 <- findpeaks(dat$Temp, npeaks = 3)
peak_val2
     [,1] 
[1,] 36.38    
[2,] 36.34   
[3,] 36.28
```

Attempt 3 - include sortstr to return peak values in decreasing order:

```
peak_val3 <- findpeaks(dat$Temp, npeaks = 3, sortstr = TRUE)
peak_val3
```

Attempt 3 results:
This is interesting because telling the code to change the order gives us completely different outputs as compared to Attempt 2. The first row gave us a correct peak value but rows 2 and 3 are incorrect.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 57.49  430  388  431
[2,] 52.45  387  384  388
[3,] 40.09  785  784  786
```

Comment: Attempt 4 - Specify the # of increasing steps and decreasing steps. Since I have a lot of data points, I'm thinking that 5 points should still work to determine the peak:

```
peak_val4 <- findpeaks(dat$Temp, npeaks = 3, nups = 5, ndowns = 5, sortstr = TRUE)
peak_val4
NULL
```


Attempt 5 - Since most of my values are above 45, I set the threshold as 45 since threshold is defined as the minimum on `findpeaks` documentation:
```
> peak_val_5
NULL
```

Comment: Attempt 6 - In this attempt, I tried to apply the same idea from Attempt 5 but instead I specified it on the minpeakheight argument. This is less ideal for long-term use because I have to plot the data first and see where do the peaks appear:
```
peak_val_6<- findpeaks(dat$Temp, minpeakheight = 45, npeaks = 3)
peak_val_6
```

Attempt 6 results:
This gave us 1 correct peak value as showed in Row 2. Row 1 is an incorrect peak value and despite requiring 3 peaks as an output, it only gave us 3.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 52.45  387  384  388
[2,] 57.49  430  388  43
```

Comment: Due to character limits I have to add attempts 4,5, and 6 in the comments.

Comment: Lastly, minpeakheight and minpeakdistance arguments do not really work well for my application because I have various datasets with varying peak heights and distances. I know that some of the questions in this forum recommended altering the peakpat argument but without a strong documentation on what the arguments mean I wasn't  able to use its full potential. I've tried peakpat = "[+]{1,}[0]*[-]{1,}"  and I know this is to catch duplicates so this doesn't really help me. I tried changing the 1s into 2s thinking that it would look at the increase or decrease on the neighboring points & no luck.